# How this is true for laws of exponents?

Tags: exponentiation

If R = $(\frac{V}{pi})^\frac{1}{3}$

If I ask you to find $R^2$.

We substitute it and make the power 2/3 as I saw in my textbook.

Why didn’t the powers add if they are multiplied.

Comment: $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}  = \frac{2}{3}  = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: 1/3 + 2 right ?

Comment: That's not how it works. By elementary properties of exponentials, $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$.

Comment: Then when do powers add.

Comment: $x^a \cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$

Comment: The powers are not added but composed.

Comment: Ok .Thank you.Silly mistake.